# Чем отличается эмулятор терминала от эмулятора консоли?

Tags: консоль, терминология, эмулятор

В сети для эмулятора терминала можно встретить такое определение:

> Эмулятор терминала, приложение терминала, term или tty для краткости — это программа, которая эмулирует терминал компьютера внутри некоторой другой архитектуры вывода данных на экран.

Не совсем понятно это определение. То есть по сути эмулятор терминала - это консоль, а эмулятор консоли - терминал?

Comment: Есть `/dev/tty{1-7}`, а есть `/dev/pts/{0-...}`. Скорее всего первое - это терминалы, а второе - консоли. Но это не точно =)

Comment: Да, чтобы увидеть, скажем, `/dev/tty1` и понять что это, нажмите `Ctrl+Alt+1`. Вернуться в GUI можно скорее всего на `Ctrl+Alt+7`.

Comment: TTY (teletype) - это древняя вещь, которая дословно переводится примерно как удаленная печать (в смысле ввод). Естественно, сейчас это все эмулируется. Также как, скажем, COM-порты.

Comment: @megorit _Но это не точно =)_ - да, не совсем точно, т.к. судя по прочтенным статьям в интернете вообще понятия "терминал" и "консоль" используют очень часто взаимозаменяемо. Изначально терминал предназначен для удаленного управления компьютером, консоль - для прямого. С этим понятно более-менее. Больше трудностей возникает со словом "эмуляция". Можно как-то простым языком объяснить что имеется в виду под этим словом?

Comment: В разговорной речи это (для меня) синонимы. Если же пытаться найти различия, то интуитивно, эмулятор терминала это программа, работающая с  окошком в графической системе (например, в X-windows), а эмулятор консоли работает с физическим терминалом в текстовом режиме. Но это, почти наверняка не точно и у кучи людей будет другое мнение. Возможно интересно будет почитать примерно на эту тему  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60641/linux-difference-between-dev-console-dev-tty-and-dev-tty0 и https://habr.com/ru/company/neobit/blog/330764/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Википедия про консоль:

> Консоль (устройство) — комплект устройств интерактивного ввода-вывода
> (дисплей, клавиатура, мышь) для управления компьютером.
>
> Консоль — радиоприёмник, радиола и т. п., выполненный в виде напольной
> тумбочки (консольное исполнение).
>
> Консоль (информатика) — интерфейс пользователя, окно для вывода
> системных сообщений и приёма команд; программное обеспечение для
> управления компьютером; программное обеспечение, реализующее текстовый
> интерфейс пользователя.
>
> Microsoft Management Console — компонент Windows 2000 и более поздних
> версий Windows.
>
> Игровая приставка (игровая консоль) — специализированное электронное
> устройство для видеоигр.
>
> Приборная панель (консоль) — группа приборов, совмещённых в одной
> конструкции.

Википедия про терминал:

> В системах связи терминал — оконечное устройство для приёма и передачи
> данных.
>
> Компьютерный терминал — устройство ввода-вывода, рабочее место на
> многопользовательских ЭВМ, монитор с клавиатурой. В графических
> оболочках UNIX-подобных операционных систем термином «терминал»
> называют эмулятор терминала.
>
> В мобильных сетях терминал — абонентский телефон (в противовес
> коммутационному оборудованию сети).
>
> В системах приёма платежей платёжный терминал используется для
> взаимодействия пользователя с системой, причём операцию производит
> пользователь карточки.
>
> POS-терминал — устройство для оплаты товаров (услуг) с помощью
> платёжных карточек, причём операцию производит кассир.
>
> Терминал сбора данных (ТСД) — стационарный, проводной или мобильный
> сканер штрихкода.

Википедия про эмулятор терминала:

> Эмулятор терминала, приложение терминала, term или tty для краткости —
> это программа, которая эмулирует терминал компьютера внутри некоторой
> другой архитектуры вывода данных на экран.
>
> Несмотря на глубокую синонимичность с оболочкой командной строки или
> текстовым терминалом, термин терминал охватывает все удалённые
> терминалы, включая графические интерфейсы. Эмулятор терминала в
> оконном интерфейсе пользователя часто называется окном терминала.
>
> По сути, терминал выступает как интерфейс, предоставляющий
> пользователю возможность взаимодействовать с консолью.
>
> Примеры терминальных программ: Terminal v1.9b by Bray, COM Port
> Toolkit, PuTTY, Qt_comport, Tera Term.

Так что же такое *терминал* и почему его надо эмулировать?

Все очень просто. Если немного разобраться в поведениях разных эмуляторов терминалов, из общего списка разнообразных фич можно выделить базовые фичи - эмуляция **терминала VT100**.

[image: VT100]

Именно выпущенный в 1978 году терминал VT100 является эталоном поведения терминала.

Терминал комплектовался отличным [пользовательским гайдом](https://www.vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/), который я рекомендую к беглому прочтению всем интересующимся (По ссылке 3е издание).
Это самое короткое руководство пользования терминалом.

Именно такие терминалы и эмулируют все эти программы с черными окошками.

Что означает термин *консоль*? На мой скромный взгляд консоль можно считать как одним из элементов управления чем-либо. Немного другая сторона абстракции.

Ну а в современном мире термин *консоль* тесно закрепился за некими приставками, подключающимися к телевизору, дающие возможность рубиться, например, в FIFA или Mortal Kombat.

Соответственно, под термином *эмулятор консоли* скорее подразумевается что-то вроде эмулятора NES, SEGA, PlayStation и проч.

Comment: офигенный (без шуток) текст от Майкрософт по теме: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/