# Что такое консоль и терминал в linux?

Tags: linux, консоль

Находил этот вопрос, но четкого ответа нет, из всех ответов я понял консоль это устройства для взаимодействия с компьютером(клавиатура,монитор), терминал, так исторически сложилось, для удаленного доступа. Но сейчас получается используются виртуальный терминал или консоль, и в итоге терминал это для работы в графической среде, а консоль это tty, в моей картине мира что консоль, что терминал одно и тоже.
Можно четкий ответ что имеется ввиду консоль сейчас в линукс, можно скрин, а что терминал(терминал я так думаю где запущена оболочка например bash).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Чем отличается эмулятор терминала от эмулятора консоли?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1236756/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%8d%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Comment: @KoVadim офигенный (без шуток) текст от Майкрософт по теме: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/

Answer (score 2):

Сейчас (особенно, если работать с ПК или по сети) трудно разделить эти устройства.

Вообще, и консоль и терминал могут быть как графическим, так и алфавитно-цифровым устройством.

Традиционно, консолью называли устройство с которого проводилась загрузка компьютера и на него начальный загрузчик и инициализируемое ядро выводили свой лог.

Все остальное -- это были терминалы.

Таким образом, сейчас, любое окошко Х-window, в котором запущен shell, я бы называл терминалом, а полноэкранные окна (традиционно в Linux на физическом графическом терминале (обычно подключен по hdmi или vga) их несколько и можно переключаться между ними) -- консолями.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/